# Error no file at "/usr/lib/<libs>" when executing macdeployqt

Tags: macos, qt, deployment

I have got an application that needs to be set up with macdeployqt, but when I call it, it tells me that it cannot find some libs into /usr/lib/ directory.

Before calling macdeployqt I have to insert 3 libs (.tx) into my .app. I used otool command to view the dependencies and here is the output of one of them :

```
RecomputeDimBlock.tx:
    RecomputeDimBlock.tx (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/OpenGL (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit (compatibility version 45.0.0, current version 1404.0.0)
    libTD_Db.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    libTD_DbRoot.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    libTD_Ge.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    libTD_Root.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    libTD_Alloc.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    libTD_Gi.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    libTD_SpatialIndex.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    libsisl.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 120.1.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1225.1.1)
```

I also insert every "libTD_xx" with my tx. And then, I relink those libs. I have made a bash script to automate those steps :

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ ! -e build/debug/MediaCad.app ]
then
    echo MediaCad.app non trouvé dans build/debug/
    echo Sortie du script
    exit 1
fi
#Création du dossier « tx » dans le .app s’il n’existe pas
if [ ! -d build/debug/MediaCad.app/Contents/tx ]
then
    mkdir -p build/debug/MediaCad.app/Contents/tx
fi


#placement des tx et des libs dans le .app
for tx in RecomputeDimBlock.tx PlotSettingsValidator.tx ThreadPool.tx libTD_Db.dylib libTD_DbRoot.dylib libTD_Gi.dylib libTD_SpatialIndex.dylib libTD_Ge.dylib libTD_Root.dylib libsisl.dylib libTD_Alloc.dylib
do
    if [ -e tx/$tx ]
    then
        echo Copie de $tx dans l’application
        cp tx/$tx build/debug/MediaCad.app/Contents/tx
    else
        echo Impossible de trouver le fichier $tx dans tx/
        echo Sortie du script
        exit 1
    fi
done


#installation des libs
cd tx/
for lib in libTD_Db.dylib libTD_DbRoot.dylib libTD_Gi.dylib libTD_SpatialIndex.dylib libTD_Ge.dylib libTD_Root.dylib libsisl.dylib libTD_Alloc.dylib
do
    echo Installation de $lib
    install_name_tool -id $lib ../build/debug/MediaCad.app/Contents/tx/$lib
    install_name_tool -change $lib @executable_path/../tx/$lib ../build/debug/MediaCad.app/Contents/MacOS/MediaCad
done


#Actualisation des dépendances
for tx in RecomputeDimBlock.tx PlotSettingsValidator.tx ThreadPool.tx
do
    for lib in libTD_Db.dylib libTD_DbRoot.dylib libTD_Gi.dylib libTD_SpatialIndex.dylib libTD_Ge.dylib libTD_Root.dylib libsisl.dylib libTD_Alloc.dylib
    do
        echo Actualisation de $lib pour $tx
        install_name_tool -change $lib @executable_path/../tx/$lib ../build/debug/MediaCad.app/Contents/tx/$tx
    done
done
cd ..

#génération du .app
echo Début de la construction de l’application
/Users/developpement/Qt/5.7/clang_64/bin/macdeployqt build/debug/MediaCad.app
echo Application construite
```

When I execute my script, everything works fine except macdeployqt. Here is the output :

```
ERROR: no file at "/usr/lib/libTD_Alloc.dylib"
ERROR: no file at "/usr/lib/libTD_DbRoot.dylib"
ERROR: no file at "/usr/lib/libTD_Gi.dylib"
ERROR: no file at "/usr/lib/libTD_Ge.dylib"
ERROR: no file at "/usr/lib/libTD_Root.dylib"
ERROR: no file at "/usr/lib/libTD_SpatialIndex.dylib"
ERROR: no file at "/usr/lib/libsisl.dylib"
```

Those libs are the ones that I copied inside my .app at the beginning.

I presume that I'm doing something wrong with install_name_tool but I can't see where ? I have spent 3 days on it so that's why I asking my question here. One last thing, I work with OS X 10.11 and Qt 5.7.

If something is not clear do not hesitate to tell me, I know my english is not perfect :)

Thank you !

Answer (score 5):

Try using the -libpath option of macdeployqt. It should point to the folder where you have got those dylib files.

Comment: It worked for me, thank you! Now I no longer have lots of fake errors in the issues tab in Qt Creator.

Comment: This worked for me too, thanks. Is it possible to point to multiple directories to find dylibs?

Comment: I never tried that. I directed all the dylibs into one target folder. I suggest you do that as well - for simplicity and robustness.